# neo4j - create unique relationship with java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a unique relationship using the Java API (from Cypher query I'm able to create unique).

For Example:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo'), 
      t=node:node_auto_index(name='The Architect') 
CREATE UNIQUE n-[r:SPEAKS_WITH]-t 
RETURN n AS Neo,r
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java API is lower level. As far as I know there's no convenience method for this, so you'll need to actually code it yourself. Untested, but you probably get the idea:

```
Transaction transaction = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
  ReadableIndex<Node> autoNodeIndex = graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
  Node n = autoNodeIndex.get("name", "Neo").getSingle();
  Node a = autoNodeIndex.get("name", "The Architect").getSingle();
  tx.acquireWriteLock(n);
  tx.acquireWriteLock(a);
  Boolean created = false;
  for(Relationship r : n.getRelationships(MyRels.SPEAKS_WITH) {
    if(r.getOtherNode(n).equals(a)) { // put other conditions here, if needed
      created = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!created) {
    n.createRelationshipTo(a, MyRels.SPEAKS_WITH);
  }
  tx.success();
} finally {
  tx.finish();
}
```

*updated for Mattias's comment*

Comment: This will not be thread safe, if there are two transaction concurrently doing this then two relationships may be created. Manually grab locks on n and a if you want it to be thread/transaction safe.

Comment: Thanks Mattias. I'll try to figure out how to do that later.

Comment: K, I think I added it in.